# Evitar una tabla mutante en ORACLE SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, trigger

Llevo un tiempo liado un con un problema de tablas mutantes en una base de datos Oracle.

Les describo la situación, tengo un paquete con métodos que van realizando una serie de acciones. En uno de los métodos de hacen varias modificaciones en diferentes tablas, pongamos tabla1, tabla2 y tabla3.
En la tabla2 tengo un trigger con un cursor que consulta la tabla1.
En este momento me salta el error de tabla mutante.

He vista que en la versión 11 de Oracle se ha implementado COMPOUND TRIGGERS, lo cual hace una captura de la información de la tabla antes de que se modifique para poder acceder a ella sin que tengamos el problema de las tablas mutantes.  Pero hasta donde yo se, esta nueva funcionalidad de los trigger solo es válida para cuando necesitas consultar la misma tabla que estas modificando y no una tercera tabla, que es lo que me pasa a mí.

¿Alguien se ha enfrentado alguna vez a esta situación, y lo ha podido solucionar de alguna manera?

Un saludo y muchas gracias

Comment: La pregunta está muy amplia en su formato actual. Efectivamente puedes usar un compound trigger porque tienes un bloque row-level y un bloque statement-level. Para poder ayudarte de forma más precisa, incluye tu código (o un ejemplo mínimo verificable) para poder responderte con código que resuelva tu problema

Comment: Agregue las tablas y el trigger para poder diagnosticar.

Answer (score 0):

La tabla mutante es porque dentro de un trigger se ejecuta un SELECT de la misma tabla a la cual pertenece el trigger.

En lineas generales la solución habitual requiere:
1-Un package donde se instancia el o los valores a validar.
2-Un trigger before for statement, que inicializa la transacción y registra el o los campos a validar.
3-Un trigger before for each row, que registra el cambio o lo que se quiere validar. 
4-Un trigger after for statement, que finaliza la transacción con el cambio o lo que se quiere validar.

La construcción precisa depende de lo que esté haciendo o validando en el trigger actual.